# I am Getting Javascript errors with Infragistics 6.3 UltraWebGrid & UltraWebTab and Framework 4.5

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, frameworks, compatibility, infragistics

We are using Infragistics Ultrawebgrid & Ultrawebtab in Asp.net application developed in .Net Framework 2.0, We are trying to open the project in the Visual Studio 2013 (Framework 4.5) and the application is converted successfully with Target Framework 2.0, but getting lot of Javascript issues when accessing the page which has been implemented with Grid Control.

Can anyone help me with this issue if you have already faced this issue or any suggestion.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards
ManoBharath M

Comment: Any more detail on what the issues are?

Answer (score 0):

The 6.3 version of the product is from 2006 and is out of support for a long time now. At the time the client-side code was supporting IE7. The current version of this product is 14.2.